# Print Particular Data From Nested JSON Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi I want to  print exact data of maple but i doesnt work please help me
there is some problem that i cant able to identify

```
$json = ' {
"Success":true,"Message":null,"Data":
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": [
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}

 }';
$yummy = json_decode($json, true);

echo $yummy['toppings'][2]['type']; //Maple
```

Comment: `toppings` is a child of `Data`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss `['Data']`:

```
$yummy['Data']['toppings'][2]['type']; //Maple `
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print_r($yummy, true);
```

gives you json to array data.

```
Array
(
    [Success] => 1
    [Message] => 
    [Data] => Array
        (
            [type] => donut
            [name] => Cake
            [toppings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5002
                            [type] => Glazed
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5006
                            [type] => Chocolate with Sprinkles
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5004
                            [type] => Maple
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So you missed Data

```
$yummy['Data']['toppings'][2]['type']
```